# Trying to import Images dataset(has images, Masks), but this error keeps on repeating

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, image-segmentation, satellite-image

Here is my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTIkH.png)

It shows an error every time

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0):

Reading from this [`git hub issue`](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/933#issuecomment-546099837) that talks about the same issue that you're having, it says the following:

> This a secondary error that basically just means the image you are
> trying to process didn't load and was empty.
>
> If you grabbed the image dara from the camera, it means the camera
> connection failed or isn't configured correctly. If you loaded an
> image file, it means the loading failed.

We can understand where this issue is comming from by looking at your code. The path to the image is malformed:

```
image = cv2.imread("r../input/C:/Users/Hp/Satellite image dataset/train_images/train/image_t8_007.jpg")
```

There are two issues here:

1. There is an attempt at using a **raw** string, but the `r` **should be outside** of the **string** and **not inside** of it
2. The path is a combination of a **relative path** and an **absolute path**

The `imread()` call should look like this:

```
image = cv2.imread(r"C:/Users/Hp/Satellite image dataset/train_images/train/image_t8_007.jpg")
```